# Hide "3D Objects" from "This PC"

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, user-folders, windows-10-pro

There are plenty of tutorial online for removing "all" of the folders from under This PC, by editing the registry.  All of the folders are removed as they are supposed to be, besides for the "3D Objects" folder.
For example: To hide the documents folder, you modify the "ThisPCPolicy" key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{f42ee2d3-909f-4907-8871-4c22fc0bf756}\PropertyBag` to "Hide".

I want to hide the 3D Objects folder from This PC only, but it should still be in Quick Access, just like I can do for all of the other folders.  How can this be accomplished? (I'm using Windows 10 Professional)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Works the same way, you just create the subkey & value if they don't already exist. The most interesting thing about this setting is that the data is case-sensitive. It must be 'Hide', not 'hide' or 'HIDE'.

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{31C0DD25-9439-4F12-BF41-7FF4EDA38722}\PropertyBag`

[image]

EDIT: THis PC Namespace. Note that there are two entries for each of the following: Documetns, Dwonloads, Pictures, Music, and Videos with one set already hidden by default. If you 'Show' those, you will see "duplicate" folders under **This PC**.

```
HKLM\...\MyComputer\NameSpace          Name            HKLM\...\FolderDescriptions
----                                   ----            ----                                  
{088e3905-0323-4b02-9826-5d99428e115f} Local Downloads {7d83ee9b-2244-4e70-b1f5-5393042af1e4}
{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A} 3D Objects      {31C0DD25-9439-4F12-BF41-7FF4EDA38722}
{1CF1260C-4DD0-4ebb-811F-33C572699FDE} My Music        {4BD8D571-6D19-48D3-BE97-422220080E43}
{24ad3ad4-a569-4530-98e1-ab02f9417aa8} Local Pictures  {0ddd015d-b06c-45d5-8c4c-f59713854639}
{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B} Downloads       {374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}
{3ADD1653-EB32-4cb0-BBD7-DFA0ABB5ACCA} My Pictures     {33E28130-4E1E-4676-835A-98395C3BC3BB}
{3dfdf296-dbec-4fb4-81d1-6a3438bcf4de} Local Music     {a0c69a99-21c8-4671-8703-7934162fcf1d}
{A0953C92-50DC-43bf-BE83-3742FED03C9C} My Video        {18989B1D-99B5-455B-841C-AB7C74E4DDFC}
{A8CDFF1C-4878-43be-B5FD-F8091C1C60D0} Personal        {FDD39AD0-238F-46AF-ADB4-6C85480369C7}
{B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641} Desktop         {B4BFCC3A-DB2C-424C-B029-7FE99A87C641}
{d3162b92-9365-467a-956b-92703aca08af} Local Documents {f42ee2d3-909f-4907-8871-4c22fc0bf756}
{f86fa3ab-70d2-4fc7-9c99-fcbf05467f3a} Local Videos    {35286a68-3c57-41a1-bbb1-0eae73d76c95}
```

---

### Edit #2 - Per-User option

The above is a machine-wide modification, and thus affects all users. To hide `3D Object` (or any other folder under `This PC`), create a CLSID-named value undetr the key:
`HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideMyComputerIcons`
If the key doesn't exist, create it.

Value:

- `Name:` `{0DB7E03F-FC29-4DC6-9020-FF41B59E513A}`
- `Type:` `REG_DWORD`
- `Data:` `1` *(1 = Hide | 0 = Show)*

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly.  Note: Although hiding the other folders may happen as soon as you change the registry, a restart may be required before the 3D Objects folder is hidden.

Comment: Is there a list or method to determine what the UUID values are for other such annoying folders?

Comment: @Skidd: See my edit...

Comment: This does not actually answer the question. When setting the value to `Hide` under `HKLM\...\FolderDescriptions`, not only is it hidden in "This PC", it's also hidden in "<username>" and "Quick access".

Comment: It can be easily added to __Quick Access__  by navigating to the _actual file system location_, e.g. `C:\Users\<UserFolder>`, right-clicking on the folder, & selecting `Pin to Quick Access`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to work only if modifying the respective values under `HKLM` but not when changing them under `HKCU`. Is there a way to achieve the same result if the administrator did not grant modification access to `HKLM`?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: Answer edited to include per-user option.

Comment: @KeithMiller Thank you for your update- unfortunately, this does not seem to work on my machine. After the modification of the registry values, I killed explorer.exe and restarted it and *3D Objects* still show in *This PC*

Comment: Interesting. I'm only able to test on a standalone machine runnig the Home edition of Windows 10. If you want to pursue this, propbably best to post your own question with details, reg exports, screenshots, etc. At the least, you might get feedback from other users as to whether or not this works for them.